# Angular - How to sort table data according to specific column

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a table with 3 colums. But I want to sort the table data according to first column (**Domain**) alphabetically. My table html is:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="tableData">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="domain">
      <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="50%">Domain</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="50%">{{config.domain}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="disable">
      <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="30%">Disabled</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="30%">{{config.disabled}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="button">
      <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="15%"></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="15%">
        <mat-icon (click)="deleteDomain(config)" style="cursor: pointer">delete_forever</mat-icon>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *cdkRowDef="let config; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

And my .ts file for this table is consisting following code :

```
private _domainData = new BehaviorSubject<Domain[]>([]);

  @Input()
  set domainData(value: Domain[]) {
    this._domainData.next(value);
  }
  displayedColumns = ['domain', 'disable', 'button'];
  tableData: Domain[];
```

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: why don't you just sort it using [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: let displayedColumns = ['domain', 'disable', 'button']; displayedColumns.sort();

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this from the TypeScript by sort method when clicked on the particular column.
I don't think you need to write this logic in the back end.

If the intention is to just display the sorted data according to your Domain column. Then, please do at blackened that would be much better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular Material, you can use [Sort Header](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview) to sort data .

Or atleast you can use the logic they provided for sorting in first example.